# Выбор номера телефона из входящих вызовов

Tags: java, android

Есть метод с выбором контакта из списка контактов:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Есть ли аналог, для выбора номера телефона, из истории входящих вызовов, чтобы так же открывалось Activity с выбором и результат обрабатывался в onActivityResult()??

Есть ли возможность это сделать, без чтения логов звонков (android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/EverythingMe/easy-content-providers

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'me.everything:providers-android:1.0.1'
}
```

Getting all calendars:

```
CalanderProvider provider = new CalendarProvider(context);
List<Calendar> calendars = provider.getCalendars().getList();
```

Документация, что можно получить

https://github.com/EverythingMe/easy-content-providers/wiki/Android-providers

Comment: Но ей же тоже нужны привилегии  - тот же `android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG`, который вы поставили условием в вопросе. И никакого окна выбора, нужно делать самому. В чём выгода библиотеки? Только в том, что журнал в список читается за вас?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно, родных интентов для этого действия нет. Зато можно напрямую читать журнал звонков, если запросить READ_CALL_LOG. Прочитайте его и выводите пользователю для выбора. [Вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786666/how-do-i-access-call-log-for-android/14050724) можно пример посмотреть